# Migration through php artisan results in an QueryException

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have read a lot of posts regarding artisan migration issues, but unfortunately none of them are applicable to my situation.

So I am running Laravel Homestead via Vagrant and I have created a new database in the Vagrant VM.

On my Ubuntu desktop I can connect to the database via DBeaver and it shows the database. Because I am running the database in a Vagrant VM, I am connected to it through 192.168.10.10 (specified in the Homestead.yaml file) and not localhost (127.0.0.1). So far so good.

I created a migration file by running the following command: `php artisan make:migration create_todo_table`. However, when I run `php artisan migrate` I get the following exception error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
Could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

The data regarding the database in my `.env` file is as follows:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.10.10
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

I have tried clearing the cache by running `php artisan config:cache` but had no luck.

Can someone give me some insight, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in fixed by editing my `php.ini` file.

For **Windows** I changed `;extension=php_pdo_mysql` to `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`.

For **Ubuntu** I changed it into `extension=pdo_mysql.so`.

After that, I still got an error stating that the connection was actively refused. I fixed this by changing `DB_HOST=localhost` to `DB_HOST=192.168.10.10`.

Hope this will help someone someday!

Answer (score 0):

DB host inside your vagrant should be localhost or 127.0.0.1 because project and database both are inside vagrant but DBeaver is outside vm so `192.168.10.10` is okay for DBeaver.

`DB_HOST=localhost`